# How do I wait for the API response in Node JS before executing next line

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, async-await

I am calling get API in node js and need to wait for response. Response it the output of Alexa Skill.

### Here is the API code:

const GetReportOnEmail = function (UserID, ReportName) {

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

    var options = {        
        uri:'https://www.xxxxx/xx/xx',
        method : 'GET'
    };        
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            res = body;
            resolve(res);
        }
        else {
            res = 'Not Found';
            reject(res);
        }            
    });       
})
```

}
module.exports.GetReportOnEmail=GetReportOnEmail;

---

This function I am calling in another js file:

```
            setTimeout(function () {
                GetReportEmail.GetReportOnEmail('userID', 'ReportName').then((resp) => {
                    speechText = resp;
                }).catch((error) => {
                    speechText = "some error occurred";
                })
            }, 20000);
```

-----Further lines of code-------

I need to wait for the response from this API before executing next line of code. How do I do That.
Regards,
Naveen

Comment: you can't wait for setTimeout to finish before running the "next line of code" ... use a promise there too - or if Promise chains are too hard for you, investigate async/await

Answer (score 1):

I would use async/await.

If you run your whole main program in an `async` function that you call immediately, you can put `await` before any function that returns a `Promise`.

either:

```js
async function mainProgram() {
  // do stuff
}

mainProgram();
```

of just

```js
(async function () {
  // do stuff
})()
```

You need a `sleep` function that returns a promise.  I usually just make one like this: (but I am sure there is somewhere to import one too)

```
function sleep(t) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(resolve, t);
  });
};
```

Then go like this:

```js
(async function() {
  await sleep(20000);
  const speechText = await GetReportEmail.GetReportOnEmail(
    'userID',
    'ReportName',
  ).catch((error) => {
    return "some error occurred";
  })
  console.log(speechText);
});
```

the above mixes and matches then/catch and async/await.  You can also do it like this:

```js
(async function() {
  await sleep(20000);
  let speechText;
  try {
    speechText = await GetReportEmail.GetReportOnEmail(
      'userID',
      'ReportName',
    )
  } catch (e) {
    speechText = "some error occurred";
  }
  console.log(speechText);
});
```

---

if you don't want to use async await

```js
setTimeout(function () {
  GetReportEmail.GetReportOnEmail(
    'userID',
    'ReportName',
  ).catch((error) => {
     return "some error occurred";
  }).then(function(resp) {
     const speechText = resp;
     // do something like
     console.log(speechText);
  });
}, 20000);
```

Just put the thing you want to do after into a `then`.

In the original you are setting a `speechTex`t variable that everybody can use, but here I just passed the value onto the next then.  So I got rid of the `then` that you had, which would have just passed on the same value it received.